# Grub2 fails to chainload Windows 7 with error "invalid signature"

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot, uefi

I've built a new UEFI 64-bit system with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 installed (on separate hard drives).  I'd like to be able to boot Windows 7 from the grub menu, but I have so far been unsuccessful in getting grub to chainload it.

After getting the grub menu, I choose the option for the command line and I can see that bootmgfw.efi is at `(hd1,gpt1)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`.  However, when I attempt to chainload I get an error:

```
grub> chainloader (hd1,gpt1)/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
error: invalid signature
```

I am not sure whether I chose the UEFI boot option when I installed Linux from the LiveCD, and so I am wondering if the grub I have is perhaps unable to chainload in this manner?  In any case I am not sure how to get the chainload to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I began to suspect when I was writing my question, the issue is that Linux was installed using MBR, so that grub was unable to chainload an EFI Windows 7.  I reinstalled Linux, this time making sure to select the UEFI boot option for the LiveCD from BIOS.  With Linux now installed with an EFI grub, I was able to add a grub menu entry for Windows 7 and chainload successfully.

I used [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Chainloading_Windows_x86_64_UEFI-GPT) to create the menu entry for Windows 7.

After doing `sudo vi /etc/grub.d/40_custom` and adding the menu entry to the end of the file, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: If you found the solution to your own problem, go ahead and mark it "answered" by clicking the checkmark next to your answer. It may help someone in the future :)

Comment: Ha yeah I will do that as soon as the site lets me; yesterday when I tried to accept my own answer it informed me I need to wait a day, and just now it says 10 hours remain.  But I'll take care of it tomorrow.